Vercel AI SDK error: UnhandledRejection: TypeError: cookies is not iterable
I'm new to the Vercel AI SDK, and I'm trying to implement some AI features in an existing NextJS app (app router, v14.2.8, using npm). I tried implementing all of the code examples from the documentation's examples page, and every time it keeps giving me this error:
unhandledRejection: TypeError: cookies is not iterable
    at get [headers map sorted] (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1844:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1865:43
    at Headers Iterator.next (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1108:26)
    at Object.sequence<sequence<ByteString>> (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1395:42)
    at webidl.converters.HeadersInit (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1902:69)
    at new Headers (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1727:36)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/patch-fetch.js:417:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I literally just copy pasted what was on the examples docs (https://sdk.vercel.ai/examples/next-app/basics/generating-object) into my existing NextJS app. None of the examples (steamText, generateObject, etc) worked, each resulted in this same error. I even checked to see if it was because of my location, because I live in Hong Kong, and OpenAI is not accessible here without a VPN, and with and without a VPN, this same error keeps appearing after I try running the code.
My sense is that this issue is unrelated to the AI SDK since it does not use cookies in any way.
Here's a list of all the existing dependencies I have. Maybe the error stems from conflicts. Is there any fix to this?
"dependencies": {
    "@ai-sdk/openai": "^0.0.56",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.3",
    "@numairawan/video-duration": "^1.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-aspect-ratio": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-context-menu": "^2.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@remotion/bundler": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/cli": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/gif": "4.0.77",
    "@remotion/google-fonts": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/lambda": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/lottie": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/player": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/renderer": "^4.0.77",
    "@remotion/shapes": "^4.0.77",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.7.2",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-react": "^0.5.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.26.0",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.11.7",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.3.1",
    "@vercel/speed-insights": "^1.0.12",
    "@vidstack/react": "^1.11.30",
    "ai": "^3.3.28",
    "and": "^0.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "geist": "^1.2.2",
    "get-video-duration": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-web": "^5.12.2",
    "lucide-react": "^0.367.0",
    "next": "^14.2.8",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "nextra": "^2.13.4",
    "nextra-theme-docs": "^2.13.4",
    "openai": "^4.58.0",
    "openai-edge": "^1.2.2",
    "pexels": "^1.4.0",
    "random-word-slugs": "^0.1.7",
    "raw-body": "^2.5.2",
    "re-resizable": "^6.9.17",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-colorful": "^5.6.1",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.6",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-player": "^2.14.1",
    "react-resizable-panels": "^1.0.6",
    "react-wavesurfer.js": "^0.0.8",
    "react-wrap-balancer": "^1.1.0",
    "remotion": "^4.0.77",
    "resend": "^3.1.0",
    "set-cookie-parser": "^2.7.0",
    "stripe": "^14.16.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "url-file-size": "^1.0.5-1",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^6.6.4",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.8",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

Downgrading packages, upgrading packages, trying different examples from the Vercel AI SDK docs, all to find the same error again and again.
